# Instance variable of multiprocessing Process in Python3 not being written on terminate

Tags: python, multiprocessing

A surprising thing which I came across while writing a logic of saving some value during process termination was a bit strange for me. Writing a toy example program to show the problem.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class A(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.till = 0
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            print(i)
            i += 1
            self.till = i
            time.sleep(1)

    def terminate(self):
        print("Terminating : {}".format(self.till))
        super(A, self).terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = A()
    obj.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    obj.terminate()
```

The output for the above program is -

```
0
1
2
3
4
Terminating : 0
```

Why is terminate() not printing out 4? Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is actually running terminate on the main process, look at this code:

```
class A(multiprocessing.Process):
def __init__(self):
    self.till = 0
    super(A, self).__init__()

def run(self):
    i = 0
    print(os.getpid())
    while True:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        self.till = i
        time.sleep(1)

def terminate(self):
    print("Terminating : {}".format(self.till))
    print(os.getpid())
    super(A, self).terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("parent pid:")
    print(os.getpid())
    print("child pid:")
    obj = A()
    obj.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    obj.terminate()
```

Will lead to the output:

```
parent pid:
12111
child pid:
12222
0
1
2
Terminating : 0
12111
```

At terminate, you are actually sending `SIGTERM` to the child process, it is done from the parent process, thus the memory is of the parent, where there was no increments to `self.till`

Answer (score 0):

**init** and terminate methods run on the main process hence the sub-process prints 0 for your terminate function. Run method only increments in the sub process. You can confirm this by using os.getpid() method in python.

Edit: This problem probably only occurs in Windows since it does not have a fork() system call like in Linux/Unix systems. Windows starts the whole module from the beginning to achieve the effect.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm using Linux and the problem occurs there.